# Sklearn GridSearchCV TypeError: 'LeaveOneOut' object is not iterable

Tags: python, scikit-learn, cross-validation, grid-search

I am trying to solve an error that I get but with no luck.

**My goal is to perform a GridSearch with Cross validation (Leave One Out) for a neural net.**
I am using sklearn and python 2.7. I have 300 samples.

Here is my code:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import LeaveOneOut
from sklearn import metrics
from sklearn.neural_network import MLPClassifier
from sklearn import grid_search

my_cv = LeaveOneOut()

param_grid = {'hidden_layer_sizes': [(249,),(500,),(250,),(10,)], 
'activation': ('relu', 'logistic'),'solver': 
('sgd','adam'),'learning_rate_init':[0.005,0.05,0.001]}

nn = MLPClassifier(alpha=0.001,random_state=1,nesterovs_momentum=True)
clf = grid_search.GridSearchCV(estimator=nn, param_grid=param_grid, cv=my_cv)
clf.fit(X, y)
print clf.best_score_
print clf.best_params_
```

The error that I get is: **TypeError: 'LeaveOneOut' object is not iterable**

Note that same thing happens if I use KFold(n_splits=300) instead of LeaveOneOut().

**UPDATE**

**SOLVED** : after replacing

```
from sklearn import grid_search
```

with

```
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
```

thanks to @mkaran

Comment: From what I understand `cv=my_cv.get_n_splits(X)` would be the same as `...(n_splits=300)` since the first returns the number of splits for the cross-validator.

Comment: @mkaran Yes. KFold(300) is the same as Leave One Out. Again, using KFold I get the same error

Comment: The correct `GridSearchCV` import is this: `from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV`. Use this and `cv=my_cv` should work properly.

Comment: @mkaran Yes that's it! I cannot fully understand the difference but the new import works fine. Thank you

Comment: Glad it helped! As for the difference, by taking a look at the code, the old implementation just handles the `cv` parameter differently under the hood (slightly different `check_cv` function).